# php round() leading mistake

Tags: magento

My website is build by magento system use for shopping. now I add a function about nice foreign price. for example:
if the price is $35.4 , it will be changed to $34.99;
if the price is $35.5 , it will be changed to $35.99;

code is : round(35.4) + 0.99;

now here is a question, my product has several options link 'type','colour'.  and different option shows different price just as the default configurable product in magento.
in the product page: price is $1000 shows $999.99, colour red + $100 shows +$99.99
,and type big +50 shows+49.99. here the total price is 1149.97. but in shopping chat the price is round(1000 + 100 +50)+0.99 = 1149.99. so I don't know how to deal with it.

some one help me ..... waiting for your advice.

Comment: am I the only person on this planet not fooled by this stupid .99 prices. Its mathematically impossible to have all your products ending with 0.99 aaaand the SUM of all products (if its not some sort of x % 10 == 1). You still can add some fancy "online discount" that lies to the user that his final price is that super .99 price again. Buuuut how do you book those in your financial system? I mean if a good costs 100, your books should not receive a payment about 99.99

Comment: round(35.5) + 0.99 = 36.99 (not 35.99). You could try floor(35.5) + 0.99 = 35.99...  see http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake. the code is :  round(35.4)-1+0.99  .so the price is 34.99

Answer (score 0):

because magento final price is calculate onFly ,you shall overwrite

```
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Helper/Data.php
```

and change method to like as . (you need add to adminhtml it option or hardcode it)

```
public function calcPriceRule($actionOperator, $ruleAmount, $price)
{
    $priceRule = 0;
    switch ($actionOperator) {
        case 'to_fixed':
            $priceRule = min($ruleAmount, $price);
            break;
        case 'to_percent':
            $priceRule = $price * $ruleAmount / 100;
            break;
        case 'by_fixed':
            $priceRule = max(0, $price - $ruleAmount);
            break;
        case 'by_percent':
            $priceRule = $price * (1 - $ruleAmount / 100);
            break;
        case 'my_custom_prices':
             //your price rules 
            break;
    }
    return $priceRule;
}
```